# Facebook Submission iOS - Binary Upload Button Not Working

Tags: ios, facebook

I submitted my application to Facebook for review, and was initially rejected. Now, I have fixed the issues and am ready to re-submit for review. However on the "Status and Review" section, under the "Items in Review", the "Upload iOS App" button does not work! When I click on it nothing happens.

It's imperative that I upload a new build to fix the issues, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a gotcha I'm missing? I'd like to avoid having to delete the app and completely start over.

One caveat - I did rename the app between submissions. Does this have any unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an internal Facebook bug that has been reported. When inspecting the page with a console open, you'll see that clicking the button throws a "500 Internal Server Error". [This bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/545180848956987/) has been filed and is currently assigned to be fixed.